# Can anyone help with Code Coverage on this Trigger

Tags: unit-test, trigger

I can't seem to get any code coverage on this trigger.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am suppose to be going live with this trigger in a few hours.

```
trigger populateCaseContact on Support_Comment__c (before insert, before update){

set<Id> caseIdSet = new set<Id>();
for(Support_Comment__c supCom: trigger.new){
    if(supCom.case__c != null){
        caseIdSet.add(supCom.case__c);
    }
}

map<id, case> caseMap = new map<id, case>([SELECT id, contactid, ownerid, owner.type, createdbyid, temporary_assignee__c from case where Id IN: caseIdSet]);

for(Support_Comment__c supCom: trigger.new){
    if(caseMap.containsKey(supCom.case__c)){
        supCom.Case_Contact__c = caseMap.get(supCom.case__c).contactId;
        supCom.Case_Temporary_Assignee__c = caseMap.get(supCom.case__c).temporary_assignee__c;
        supCom.Case_Created_By_User__c = caseMap.get(supCom.case__c).createdbyid;

    if(caseMap.get(supCom.case__c).owner.type != 'Queue'){
         supCom.Case_Owner__c = caseMap.get(supCom.case__c).ownerId;
         }
    }       
}
```

}

My current testclass is below

```
@isTest(seeAllData = True)
private class TestpopulateCaseContact{
static testMethod void TestpopulateCaseContact(){

if(!test.isrunningtest()) {


list<user> UserList = [SELECT id, UserType FROM user WHERE UserType = 'Standard' and isactive=true LIMIT 1];
list<user> temp = [SELECT id, User_Type__c, profileid FROM user WHERE User_Type__c = 'Internal Community User' and profileid = '00e38000001FkY4' and isactive=true LIMIT 1];
list<user> cby = [SELECT id, User_Type__c, profileid FROM user WHERE User_Type__c = 'Customer Community User' and profileid = '00e38000001FkY3' and isactive=true LIMIT 1];
list<contact> con2 = [SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM contact WHERE firstname != 'On behalf of' LIMIT 1];

Case c = new Case();
c.ownerid = UserList[0].id;
c.contactid = con2[0].id;
c.createdbyid = cby[0].id;
c.temporary_assignee__c = temp[0].id;
insert c;

Support_Comment__c supC = new Support_Comment__c();
supC.Case__c = c.id;
supC.Comment__c = 'Test';
supC.Public__c = False;
supC.CreatedById = UserList[0].Id;
supC.case_contact__c = c.contactid;
supC.case_temporary_assignee__c = c.temporary_assignee__c;
supC.case_created_by_user__c = c.createdbyid;
supC.case_owner__c = c.ownerid;
insert supC;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share Your current test code

Comment: I have added it to my original question above

Comment: Why are you using test.isrunningtest in the test class?

Comment: without it I am getting this error when running the test 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts'

Comment: The strange thing is that this is a trigger in production with 100% coverage.  All I did was added the last few lines in the trigger to populate a few more fields and now I can't get any coverage.  I don't understand why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!test.isrunningtest()) {
```

You're in a testMethod, so this will always be false, and therefore none of your test will actually run.

Comment: So how do I get the above test to run without using the 'if(!test.isrunningtest()){' and not recieve the error message 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts'

Comment: @user25814 You need to set up a [HttpCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

Comment: Then my test will fail with the error message I mentioned above

Comment: I will give that a try.

Comment: @user25814 Also, [Testing Apex Callouts using HttpCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html) gives a working example of how to use it.

Comment: I was able to get my trigger to deploy successfully with 100% code coverage.  Thanks for your assistance

Comment: @user25814 - If you test still looks like what you posted, please be aware it is not actually testing anything. All it is doing is covering lines. At a minimum you should be querying the record in the trigger and asserting that the value were set properly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sdfcfox answer, unless you use `RunAs(cby[0].id)`, I don't believe the line `c.createdbyid = cby[0].id;` can be used. The `createdbyId` is defaulted on create to the running user context who creates the record. That's the User who needs to be running your code at the time the record is inserted. You can change the RunAs User at any time.

BTW, there's no need to use `list<user> cby = [SELECT... LIMIT 1];` Instead you can use `user cby = [SELECT... LIMIT 1];` eliminating the need to use your array notation as above where you did `cby[0].Id`. Instead, you could refer directly to `cby.Id`. With `Limit 1` Apex knows you don't need to use a list.